# Atoi реализация

Tags: c++

Нужно реализовать функцию atoi, чтобы она конвертировала число с несколькими разрядами.

```
    int atoi(string str) {
      int x=0;
      for (int i = 0; i < size(str); i++) {
        x = int(str[i]) - int('0'); 
      }
      return x;
    }
```

я сделал так, только мне оно будет переводить каждое число (я ввожу '125', а оно мне выведет 1, 2, а потом 5, т.е. отдельно)
мне нужно чтобы вывелось 100, потом 20 и наконец 5
помогите пожалуйста

Comment: что-то я не понял - если вы передадите этой функции 125, то единственное что она вам вернет - это 5. Это не соответствует тому что вы говорите

Comment: каждую итерацию вы должны добавлять к x `10 * count_of_symbols_to_end_of_string_from_current_location * cur_value`. Ну и я бы подумал насчет проверки того, является ли символ в строке числом прежде, чем его конвертить

Comment: int atoi(string str)
{
 int x=0;
 for (int i = 0; i < size(str); i++)
 {
  x +=( int(str[i]) - int('0') )+10*(size(str)-i)*i; 
 }
 return x;
}
Вот так?

Comment: зачем вы еще и на i домнажанте?

Comment: а вместо умножения на 10... используете сложение

Comment: можете написать итоговый вариант пожалуйста

Comment: Да и я там допустил опечатку в комменте не `10 * ...` а `10 ^ ...` тобишь в степень возвести. Нужно определенное количество нулей

Comment: нет. Вам же тогда ничего не достанется)

Comment: x +=( int(str[i]) - int('0') )+pow(10, (size(str)-i)*i);
мне кажется, оно наоборот работает,

Comment: опять на i домножили - писал же чтоб убрали. Ну а в остальном вроде верно

Comment: но что не так с i? i здесь как положение числа в строке

Comment: ага, и у вас оно почему-то используется дважды - невидите что ли?

Comment: и не вижу, и не понимаю(

Comment: ну а `size(str) - i` - что по-вашему?

Answer (score 4):

Возможная реализация:

```
#include <cctype>

int atoi(const char* str)
{
  int number = 0;
  int sign = 1;

  if (*str == '+' || *str == '-') {
    if (*str == '-') {
      sign = -1;
    }
    ++str;
  }

  while (std::isdigit(*str)) {
    number = number * 10 + (*str - '0');
    ++str;
  }

  return number * sign;
}
```

Входная строка должная быть нуль-терминированной, алгоритм прост: проходимся по строке если очередной символ цифра то умножаем наше итоговое число на 10 и прибавляем эту цифру к числу иначе выходим из цикла и возвращаем число. Поведение в случае ошибки нужно определить под свои нужды, в этой реализации возвращает ноль если строка не числовая с самого начала

Comment: можно `0xf & *str` вместо `*str - '0'`